# SQL Replication Fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication

I have set up a new publication to publish one table in my database (tbl_User)

When i start the agent  I get to this point

[97%] Locking published tables while generating the snapshot

Then fails with the following error

> Error messages: Message: Failed to create AppDomain
>   "mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].128".  Exception has been thrown by
>   the target of an invocation. Failed to create AppDomain
>   "mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].129".  Exception has been thrown by
>   the target of an invocation.  Command Text: if
>   object_id('sys.sp_replcleanupccsprocs') < 0 exec
>   sp_replcleanupccsprocs @publication Parameters:   @publication =
>   PercyPub
>
> Stack:    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.ReMapSqlException(SqlException
>   e, SqlCommand command)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.AgentExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand
>   command, Int32 queryTimeout)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.ExecuteDiscardResults(CommandSetupDelegate
>   commandSetupDelegate, Int32 queryTimeout)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.TransSnapshotProvider.CleanCCSCompensationProcsCommand(SqlConnection
>   connection)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.RetryableSqlServerTransactionManager.ExecuteTransaction(Boolean
>   bLeaveTransactionOpen)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.TransSnapshotProvider.DoConcurrentPostArticleFilesGenerationProcessing()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.GenerateSnapshot()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.SnapshotGenerationAgent.InternalRun() 
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.Run() (Source:
>   MSSQLServer, Error number: 6517) Get help: http:// help/6517 Server
>   SQL, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSpost_auto_proc, Line 88 Failed
>   to create AppDomain "mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].129".  Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (Source: MSSQLServer,
>   Error number: 6517) Get help: http:// help/6517 Server SQL, Level 16,
>   State 1, Procedure sp_MSpost_auto_proc, Line 88 Failed to create
>   AppDomain "mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].129".  Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error
>   number: 6517) Get help: http:// help/6517

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was that my sql server memory was near its limit and increasing it + restart fixed it.

Comment: If your 'max server memory' setting is not set to something reasonably under your server's RAM, consider setting it down. I use this script: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/james-sql-footprint/2012/06/02/max-server-memory/